# Python3 how append represent simple dependency graph for boot sequence

Tags: python-3.x, class

My problem is to create a list of servers, which have to reboot in a sequence. Like: 
if server01 has booted, then server02a and server02b may boot, after server02a comes server03, etc. So I created the class Server and tried to append some servers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class Server:
    def __init__(self, name, nextsrv=[]):
         self.name = name
         self.nextsrv = nextsrv
         print(self.name)

servers = []

servers.append(Server('server01'))
servers.append(Server('serverXX'))
servers[0].nextsrv.append(Server('server02a'))
```

- How to add more instances? The next one, server02b, is not accepted.
- How to add servers in nextsrv of server02[ab]?
- How to loop over this lists in lists in instances?

Comment: It looks like you tried to make a linked-list setup. Why not just put all the servers in a single list, then iterate down that list, booting the servers in order? Why have `self.nextsrv`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate. Because some servers may take longer to boot, but others will not depend on them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ahh, guess that makes sense. Might be easier to have a second class with multiple "dependency chains" (lists), and then append to each list the servers that are dependant on each other. I can see chaining instances through internal lists getting messy.

Comment: Nominally, you could just use lists to describe the dependencies: `[['server01'], ['server02a', 'server02b'], ['server03']]` or even make a list in a config file. Whether you need something more complicated depends on how you want to use the data. For instance, how are these dependencies decided and how do you want to use the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would maintain two different structures: a tree of servers and their dependencies, and the list of currently booting servers. This would involve expanding the server class a bit to allow for more complex graph structures:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, name, nextsrv=None):
        self.name = name
        self.booted = False
        self.nextsrv = set()
        if nextsrv is not None:
            self.add_srvs(nextsrv)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Server) and self.name == other.name
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
    def boot(self):
        # Do some magic here
        self.booted = True
    def add_srv(self, srv):
        self.nextsrv.add(srv)
        srv.depends.add(self)
    def add_srvs(self, srvs):
        for srv in srvs:
            self.add_srv(srv)
    def has_depends(self):
        for srv in self.depends:
            if not srv.booted:
                return True
        return False
```

I have turned `nextsrv` into a set, which means that `Server` needs a `__hash__` method. Servers are compared by name only. I also added a backreference to the dependent server so that it becomes easy to check when a server is bootable, i.e., not in the `nextsrv` list of another unbooted server.

Now you can set up the server tree as you described. I would just make a dict that allows you to do something like:

```
servers = {}
servers['server03'] = Server('server03')
servers['server02a'] = Server('server02a', servers['server03'])
servers['server02b'] = Server('server02b')
servers['server01'] = Server('server01', [x for x in servers.values() if x.name in ('server02a', 'server02b')])
```

You could assign each server to a different variable, but I think it is easier to manage a lot of different servers via a dict. It also allows you to do stuff like computing the boot sequence automatically:

```
from collections import deque

# Startup: find all servers that no-one depends on
boot_candidates = deque((x for x in servers.items if not x.depends))
# Iteration with for will break if we extend the list during iteration
while boot_candidates:
    srv = boot_candidates.popleft()
    srv.boot()
    boot_candidates.extend(x for x in srv.nextsrv if not x.hasdepends())
```

This solution does not check for cyclic dependencies and other complexities. However, it does have the advantage of being highly paralellizable, which is probably something you should look into, especially since booting a server should consume very few resources on the local machine (unless you have VMs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This complete answer helped me all the way further. Making a dictionary  'servers' (instead of a list) was a great suggestion too.